# Having trouble following return of recursive python function with exceptions

Tags: python

I have a decorator called traced that draws lines that connect function calls to their recursive return values.

```
class traced(object):
    __nested=0      
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.__f=f
        self.__name__=f.__name__
    def __call__(self,*args,**dargs):
        l=0
        arguments=""
        for arg in args:
            if(l!=0):
                arguments+=", "
            arguments +=str(arg)
            l=l+1
        items=dargs.iteritems()
        for i in items:
            if(l!=0):
                arguments+=", "
            arguments +=(str(i[0])+" = "+str(i[1]))
            l=l+1
        print("| "*type(self).__nested),
        print(",- "+self.__name__+"("+arguments+")")
        type(self).__nested+=1
        try:
            rv = self.__f(*args,**dargs)
            type(self).__nested+=-1
            print("| "*type(self).__nested),
            print("`- "+repr(rv))
            return rv
```

Here is an example of it running with this function:

```
 >>> @traced
>>> def foo(a,b):
...    if a==0: return b
...    return foo(b=a-1,a=b-1)
...
>>> foo(4,5)

,- foo(4, 5)
| ,- foo(a=4, b=3)
| | ,- foo(a=2, b=3)
| | | ,- foo(a=2, b=1)
| | | | ,- foo(a=0, b=1)
| | | | `- 1
| | | `- 1
| | `- 1
| `- 1
`- 1
1
```

I need it to run correctly with functions that raise exceptions and a function is provided that I need it to be able to run with, but Im not sure how to edit my decorator because I cant follow the function's output.
Here is the function:

```
class ChangeException(Exception):
    pass

@traced
def change_t(l,a):
    if a==0:
        return []
    elif len(l)==0:
        raise ChangeException()
    elif l[0]>a:
        return change_t(l[1:],a)
    else:
        try:
            return [l[0]]+change_t(l,a-l[0])
        except ChangeException:
            return change_t(l[1:],a)
```

and the provided output:

```
change_t([9, 7, 5], 44):
,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 44)
| ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 35)
| | ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 26)
| | | ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 17)
| | | | ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 8)
| | | | | ,- change_t([7, 5], 8)
| | | | | | ,- change_t([7, 5], 1)
| | | | | | | ,- change_t([5], 1)
| | | | | | | | ,- change_t([], 1)
| | | | | | ,- change_t([5], 8)
| | | | | | | ,- change_t([5], 3)
| | | | | | | | ,- change_t([], 3)
| | | | | | | ,- change_t([], 8)
| | | | ,- change_t([7, 5], 17)
| | | | | ,- change_t([7, 5], 10)
| | | | | | ,- change_t([7, 5], 3)
| | | | | | | ,- change_t([5], 3)
| | | | | | | | ,- change_t([], 3)
| | | | | | ,- change_t([5], 10)
| | | | | | | ,- change_t([5], 5)
| | | | | | | | ,- change_t([5], 0)
| | | | | | | | `- []
| | | | | | | `- [5]
| | | | | | `- [5, 5]
| | | | | `- [5, 5]
| | | | `- [7, 5, 5]
| | | `- [7, 5, 5]
| | `- [9, 7, 5, 5]
| `- [9, 9, 7, 5, 5]
`- [9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5]
[9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5]
```

my current output:

```
>>> change_t([9, 7, 5], 44)
 ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 44)
|  ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 35)
| |  ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 26)
| | |  ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 17)
| | | |  ,- change_t([9, 7, 5], 8)
| | | | |  ,- change_t([7, 5], 8)
| | | | | |  ,- change_t([7, 5], 1)
| | | | | | |  ,- change_t([5], 1)
| | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([], 1)
| | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([5], 8)
| | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([5], 3)
| | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([], 3)
| | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([], 8)
| | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([7, 5], 17)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([7, 5], 10)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([7, 5], 3)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([5], 3)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([], 3)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([5], 10)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([5], 5)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  ,- change_t([5], 0)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- []
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [5]
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [5, 5]
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [5, 5]
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [7, 5, 5]
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [7, 5, 5]
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [9, 7, 5, 5]
| | | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [9, 9, 7, 5, 5]
| | | | | | | | | | | |  `- [9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5]
[9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 5]
```

I understand how change_t gets to this change_t([], 3), but dont understand why the next call is change_t([], 8). 
Also Im not sure how I would change my decorator to handle exceptions correctly.

Comment: I must confess, that's a pretty neat decorator.

Comment: What is in the `except` block in the decorator?

Comment: the except block is in the change_t function not the decorator.  Im having trouble understanding the recursive flow of that function so thats why I posted this. I know I need to make a try and except block in the decorator to account for exceptions but im not sure where to place it

Comment: @AnatoliySokolov The `raise ChangeException()` in the first `elif` is not caught in the function, but in the decorator code. So it matters what you have there...